# What is wrong with this JSON file? - Parse error

Tags: json, jekyll

I have this JSON file: https://gist.github.com/ty221/70f9d71e55ce9bc36bd5

I want to load it using Jekyll. Unfortunately, but JSONLint.com there is syntax mistake in my code. Exactly, there:

```
{
        "name": "Nguyen Thi Thao Nguyen",
        "website": "",
        "interests": "- Learn more information about free and open software",
        "org": "            a:2:{i:0;s:48:\"-   Vietnam National University - Ho Chi Minh City\";i:1;s:33:\"University of  Economics and Law.\";}          " //there is an error!!!
},
```

Error is:

```
Parse error on line 420:
...re",        "org": "            a:2:{i:
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

I am not sure what is causing the mistake. Everything is propely backslashed, there are commas, etc. Can you give me any advice?

Comment: I get `Valid JSON` when I remove `//there is an error!!!`

Comment: @BilltheLizard rlemon is right, but you must copy from the gist not from the question to see the tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on line 420 there is an extra tab character. removing it allows the JSON to be validated at least through JSON Lint as valid JSON.

I have created a series of screenshots to highlight the finding.

[image]

Note: As @dystroy says in the comments, you can replace the tab with `\t` instead of removing it.

Comment: Comic Sans 420, this is a post I can get behind.

Comment: Instead of removing that tab it's possible to use `\t` in JSON

Answer (score 1):

You have and extra comma at the end of json. And remove the '//there is an error!!!' from the last line.  Here is a working version:

```
{
    "name": "Nguyen Thi Thao Nguyen",
    "website": "",
    "interests": "- Learn more information about free and open software",
    "org": "            a:2:{i:0;s:48:\"-   Vietnam National University - Ho Chi Minh City\";i:1;s:33:\"University of  Economics and Law.\";}"
}
```

Comment: The code in the question is just part of a bigger JSON string (see gist)

Comment: But I did not change anything except remove the '//there is an error!!!' and the comma from the json OP pasted. and it validates green on jsonlint.com. No changes to tab chars or anything. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/Km2YEke.png) is the screenshot.

Comment: You're just not helping : the real question is related to the code in the gist